# What information is kept by a non-running docker container?

Tags: docker

[Manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/glossary/#container) says that a Docker container consists of:

- A Docker image
- Execution environment
- A standard set of instructions

Image is pretty straightforward. If no process is running (container is stopped), what execution environment is there? Also, what are "standard instructions"?

If `docker ps -a` shows two different (stopped) containers of the same image, how much can they differ?

Comment: Different mounts, different networks, different published ports, ...

Comment: Also a stopped container can be very different from another, and from the image it is based on. For example you can start a fresh container, update your ruby / php / nodejs version and stop it. The stopped container will still have the updated software on it.